# What is wrong with this factoring by completing the square?

Tags: factoring

This is the problem and my attempt at solution:

$3x^2 + 2x - 1 = $

$3(x^2 + \frac{2}{3}x - \frac{1}{3}) = $

$3(x^2 + 2x + 1 - \frac{4}{3}x - \frac{4}{3}) = $

$3[(x + 1)^2 - \frac{4}{3}x - \frac{4}{3}] = $

$3(x + 1)^2 - 4x - 4 = $

$3(x + 1)^2 - 4(x + 1) = $

$(x + 1)(3(x + 1) - 4) = $

$(x + 1)(3x - 1)$

However the textbook says this is the solution:

$(x + 1)(x - \frac{1}{3})$

Did I mess something up with the $3$ coefficient? I can't seem to notice what my mistake is.

Comment: It's a matter of how you want to express your answer.  The roots are still $-1,\frac{1}{3}$ either way if your original expression was equal to zero.

Comment: Your textbook is wrong.  They probably meant to write $3(x+1)(x-\frac{1}{3})$.  Both that and your answer are correct factorizations.

Comment: What do you mean? In the book answer, $(x - /fac{1}{3}$ is different in value from mine

Comment: Oh ok thatnks then!

Comment: @darkradeon.  You are right. The book is wrong. The coefficient of $x^2$ should be 3, as shown in your answer. But it is 1 as shown in the answer from the book.

Comment: Usually you want to factorize to the form:
$$\alpha(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$
This way some important information is readily available. The coefficient of the highest degree is $\alpha$ and the roots are $r_1$ and $r_2$. This extends to higher order polynomials as well; the number of roots will just be the same as the order of the polynomial.

Comment: @darkradeon After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1):

expanding your result you will get $$3x^2+3x-x-1=3x^2+2x-1$$ it is the same term as in your exercise.

Answer (score 0):

$(x+1)(3x+1)$ is the same as $3(x+1)(x+\frac13)$, because $3x+1=3(x+\frac13)$. Are you sure that the book doesn't say $3(x+1)(x+\frac13)$?